# How to update libpoppler?

Tags: pdf

Poppler 0.20.4 isn't able to render specific pdf files the right way. How can I upgrade libpoppler to the newest version?

I use Xubuntu 12.10 and tried to open the pdf with evince zathura an so on . 
None of them could open the file. So I think the problem is the libpoppler. 
But how can I patch it?

Comment: no one ? 
no chance to open the pdf ?

Answer (score 1):

You have the option to build it from source. You may download the latest poppler version from [the official website](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/). At the time of writing, this is [Poppler 0.22.3](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/poppler-0.22.3.tar.gz).

Then you would build and install it:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr \
    --sysconfdir=/etc \
    --disable-static  \
    --enable-xpdf-header
make
sudo make install
```

I have successfully tested this with Ubuntu 13.04. From there on, you can also upgrade zathura if you want to, by building the latest `zathura` and `zathura-pdf-poppler`-plugin. The latest `zathura` version in the repositories is over a year old so that might be of interest for you.